# 405 Method Not Allowed response: { "message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."}

Tags: api, jwt, laravel-7, guzzle

I created an API with **tymon/jwt-auth**, I test it on **POSTMAN** and it works very well, but when I want to consume it with **Guzzle** I encountered this error :

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException Client error: `POST http://localhost/project/public/api/stands/1/images2/` resulted in a
> `405 Method Not Allowed` response: { "message": "The GET method is not
> supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.", "exception":
> "Symfony\ (truncated...)

**Route** for **API** :

```
Route::post('stands/{id}/images2', 'ImageController@store');
```

**Controller** ImageController.php for **API** :

```
public function store(Request $request, $id) {

      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
          [ 
          'nom' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png'
         ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {          
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);                        
     }
   
    if ($files = $request->file('nom'))
    {
        

         $path = public_path() . '/images/';
         $files->move($path, $files->getClientOriginalName() );
         
       
        $image = new Image();
        $image->nom =  $files->getClientOriginalName();
       // $image->stand_id= $request->stand_id;
        $stand = $this->user->stands()->find($id);
        if ($stand->images()->save($image)){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                "message" => "File successfully uploaded"
                

            ]);
        $image->save();
         }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, image could not be added'
            ], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

**Form** :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('postImage',request()->route('id')) }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field("post")}}
                            <!--begin::Card-->
                            <div class="card card-custom gutter-b example example-compact">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <div class="card-title">
                                        <h3 class="card-label">
                                            Upload
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                                            <div class="box-browse" >
                                                <div class="custom-file">
                                                    <input type="file" name="nom" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                                                </div>
                                                  
                                                <div class="content-upload">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="form-text text-muted">Allowed file types: png, jpg,
                                                    jpeg.</span>
                                          
                                                <!-- <div class="custom-file">
                                                  
                                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose
                                                        file</label>
                                                </div> -->

                                            </div> 
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--end::Card-->
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ok" />
                        </form>
```

**Controller** Admin\ImageController.php that consumes API for upload file  :

```
public function store(Request $request, $id){
    
             $file               = $request->file('nom');
            $file_path          = $file->getPathname();
            $file_mime          = $file->getMimeType('image');
            $file_uploaded_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            
            $url = "http://localhost/project/public/api/stands/".$id."/images2/";
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    
        try {  
            $response = $client->post($url, 
                 
               [
                 'multipart' => [
                 [
                    'name'     => 'nom',
                    'filename' => $file_uploaded_name,
                    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form_data',
                    'contents' => fopen($file_path, 'r'),]
                ],
                 'headers' => 
                    [
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.Session::get('token'),
                        'Accept' => 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form_data',
                    ]
    
             
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
    
    }
```

the **route** :

```
Route::post('/stands/{id}/images2/', 'Admin\ImageController@store')->name('postImage');
```